# Split all form inputs on colon and wrap in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I'm struggling with how best to do this and am hoping for some advice.

For all of the inputs in this form, I need to split the label at the colon (`:`) and wrap a span around the latter half of the label, to achieve something like this: `<label>Regular: <span class="price">$135 (1 Year) or $225 (2 Year)</span></label>`.

Would RegEx be the best route to implement this? I'm not sure how to go about it, this is a little more complex than my knowledge of RegEx.

```
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-radios" id="webform-component-discount-options">

<div id="edit-submitted-discount-options" class="form-radios">

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-1" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="none" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-1">Regular: $135 (1 Year) or $225 (2 Year) </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
 <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-2" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="senior" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-2">Senior: $108 (1 Year) or $180 (2 Year) </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-3" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="student" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-3">Student: $81 (1 Year) </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-4" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="nonresident" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-4">Non-Resident: $108 (1 Year) or $180 (2 Year) </label>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are several problems with this question: First, it may be an [XY problem](√).  _Why_ do you "need" to do this, and do this with JavaScript? Second, you are expected to show your research, and your attempt to solve the problem yourself.  As-is, you haven't shown any effort...

Comment: Yes, a regular expression would be an easy way to do this. Use a capture group to get everything after the colon, and then put that inside the span in the replacement.

Comment: Try going to regular-expressions.info and read the tutorial section on capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're simply curious how to automate this as an **editing task** (one that seems repetitive to do manually in your code editor).

Even though it is easy enough to do this manually for 4 inputs, you could indeed accomplish it also with a regular expression instead.

A regular expression similar to `/(?<=: )[^<]+/gm;` can assist in finding and replacing in the manner you've described. For example, Run the code snippet below:

```js
let html = `<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-radios" id="webform-component-discount-options">

<div id="edit-submitted-discount-options" class="form-radios">

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-1" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="none" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-1">Regular: $135 (1 Year) or $225 (2 Year) </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
 <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-2" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="senior" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-2">Senior: $108 (1 Year) or $180 (2 Year) </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-3" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="student" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-3">Student: $81 (1 Year) </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-4" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="nonresident" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-4">Non-Resident: $108 (1 Year) or $180 (2 Year) </label>
</div>

</div>
</div>`;

let rx = /(?<=: )[^<]+/gm;

html = html.replace(rx,`<span class="price">$&</span>`);
console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### It's generally a bad idea to parse HTML with Regex.

HTML isn't a regular language, so regular expressions are not adequately equipped to deal with it. Seriously. [You could summon cthulhu.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7431860)

That being said, if you know your `<label>` tags are only on one line, are all properly formatted, and you're *really* determined to use regex, this will do the trick:

`<label.*?>.*?:(.*?)<\/label>`

It gets an opening `label` tag, reads to the first instance of a colon, and then captures everything after that until it hits the label's close tag. [See a demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/w9jQL8/1/)

**This only works for your posted examples.** If there's another attribute after the label, or you have nested label tags (for some reason), or a colon appears anywhere else in the label, the regex is going to break. If you're already in JS, it's probably a much better idea to just use `element.innerText` to get the text and then alter it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This method works without impacting DOM by ensuring no children exist when editing the contents.

```js
$("label.option").each(function(x) {
  if($(this).children().length == 0) {
    var t = $(this).text();
    var r = t.replace(/(.*?:\s*)(.*?)\s*$/, '$1<span>$2</span>');
    $(this).html(r);
    console.log(r)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-radios" id="webform-component-discount-options">

<div id="edit-submitted-discount-options" class="form-radios">

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-1" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="none" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-1">Regular: $135 (1 Year) or $225 (2 Year) </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
 <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-2" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="senior" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-2">Senior: $108 (1 Year) or $180 (2 Year) </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-3" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="student" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-3">Student: $81 (1 Year) </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-submitted-discount-options">
   <input type="radio" id="edit-submitted-discount-options-4" name="submitted[discount_options]" value="nonresident" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-discount-options-4">Non-Resident: $108 (1 Year) or $180 (2 Year) </label>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```